# Best way to spawn 100s of UI gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, uielement

As the title states, i'm looking for a good method that isn't to performance heavy to spawn UI gameobjects (from a prefab) into a scroll rect.

I've done `Instantiate` with `IEnumerator` and it works, it just takes forever with 600 UI elements.

I know this isn't what the question is about, but would there be a good way to 'smoothly' run 500+ ui elements in a scroll rect with minimum lag? Because my application is at like 2 FPS....

Would anyone know any good methods? Would pooling work for this?

Comment: Are you looking for an efficient way to spawn prefabs or an an efficient way to run 500+ui elements in a scroll rect without lag? If you spawn them it should just be a lag while spawning and not afterwards.

Comment: Well, more or less ,im looking for a way to do both efficient. There is lag afterwards, and lag before. Keep in mind, (idk if this makes a diffrence) but the spawn ubjects, are buttons, with 2 scripts on them. I did remove the animator which seems like it boosted the performance alot.